# Scrollview also scrollable if mouse over content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, scrollview

I added a Scrollview around a textlabel.
It works pretty fine, but I can only scroll, when the mouse is exactly over the scrollbar.

Is there a way to scroll as well, if the mouse is over the content (in this case the textlabel)?

The part of the `XAML`-file looks like this:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,498,0,15" Width="231">
        <Label Content="Abstand zu &#x0a;Konturgeradek&#x0a;ajs&#x0a;d&#x0a;h&#x0a;f&#x0a;l&#x0a;k&#x0a;j&#x0a;a&#x0a;s&#x0a;h&#x0a;d&#x0a;f&#x0a;l&#x0a;kjassdbnflakruf"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Here are two picutes: In the right one I can scroll with the mouse wheel, in the left one nothing happens if I scroll on the mouse wheel ...

[image]

Comment: do you mean to scroll via mousewheel, or even dragging the content?

Comment: You can scroll using mouse wheel when mouse is over content

Comment: @MarioVernari: i want to scroll via mouse wheel

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Scrolling by mouse wheel should just work by default.

Comment: @Clemens but it DOESN'T work, if the mouse is NOT over the scrollbar

Comment: For me it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced same issue this helped me ::
add this method to your scroll viewer as follows

```
<ScrollViewer 
    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    Margin="0,498,0,15" Width="231" 


    PreviewMouseWheel="ListViewScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel">
```

and change code behind as follows::

```
private void ListViewScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer scv = (ScrollViewer)sender;
        scv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(scv.VerticalOffset - e.Delta / 7);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: nice! that worked really well! i don't quite understand, why this is not native implemented ... and I don't quite understand either, why you got a down-rate of somebody ;)